# WYSIWYG editor override page css?

Tags: html, css, email, wysiwyg, inline

I have a web application that allows the creation of HTML emails that can then be dispatched. Because of how fiddly HTML email display can be, I have an open-source WYSIWYG editor embedded.

The editor itself works fantastically, but with one problem that you may already be thinking. Basically, the page CSS is conflicting with the inline CSS generated by the text editor, which caused issues for things like tables.

Currently I am solving this on the "preview" page by placing the preview in an iframe but I am not entirely sure the best way to do this for the actual editor page. If I do it in an iframe, I would either have to put it into a separate page and alter the process slightly, or write some Javascript to strip the HTML out of the iframe on form submit.

It seems like there should be an easier way - has anyone solved this problem before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would switch to a different editor like CKEditor or TinyMCE that allows you to edit the whole HTML by using themselves an iframe for the edited contents. That way you can edit exactly what you will send.

One example: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/fullpage.html

Answer (score -1):

Change how you are targeting your selectors. If you have conflicts, then your CSS is not written efficiently.

Maybe use a root `div` with a specific ID and have everything cascade off of that.